# Adding QtLua to a QtCreator project

Tags: qt, qt4, lua

Well i have a folder called libqtlua-1.4 in which i have the libqtlua.so, the qtlua executable, and in libqtlua-1.4/src/QtLua i have the headers.

How can i include it in a qtcreator project?
(I am running in ubuntu 11.10)

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the library in you project file (file with .pro extension) to qmake be able to see them when compile:

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/your/lib/libqtlua-1.4 -lqtlua
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/your/lib/libqtlua-1.4/src/QtLua
```

References: [LIBS](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#id-66e124da-ff0b-466a-8f92-2f4d5a78da4b), [INCLUDEPATH](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#id-cb5803da-df55-4b1f-9916-c9dd845da133).